# Make route command persistent after reboot

Tags: 20.04, netplan, router

Quick question:

I want to make this command persistent after reboot:

```bsh
route add -net 10.0.8.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.3.121.244
```

I tried playing with the `netplan` yaml files with no success, my original 00_....yaml file was only the first 3 lines. I put this:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      addresses: [10.0.8.0/24]
      gateway4: 10.3.121.244
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

But is doesnt seems to work. I don't really know what to put on nameservers... It appears that our DCHP is dynamic but always assigns the same IP based on the mac address of the computer. I am on 20.04 Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

netplan configuration should be a bit different:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp4s0: 
      dhcp4: true
      routes:
      - to: 10.0.8.0/24
        via: 10.3.121.244
```

After that changes have to be applied by:

```
netplan apply
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the graphical user interface for persistent routes. Go to Settings->network and edit IPv4 settings.

For eg. If you want to route to `10.190.10.16/32` via `172.18.29.1` router

[image]

It also works for source based routing. The next routing is configured to be all requests that are coming from `10.204.182.92` to be routed via `172.18.29.1.`

For default routing use `0.0.0.0/0.`